# Using EL expression in JSTL

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, xss, jsp-tags

I've been given some code to fix for XSS vulnerability.
A task is to safely escape all the current code JSP expressions.

I'm using JSTL to do this. I don't have the freedom to refactor, just to make it safe. The logic and variables are in a scriptlet which I can't change.

What is the best way to do this?

Is the following a workable solution.

Before:

```
<% String myVar = "string" %>
<%= myVar %>
```

After:

```
<% String myVar = "string %>
<c:out value="<%= myVar %>"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Avoid scriptlets as much as you can and convert them to JSTL. You could do it this way:

```
<c:set var = "myVar" scope = "session/request/page (not required and page is default)" value = "string-value"/>
<c:out value = "${myVar}"/>
```

Comment: Unfortunately the code has logic and all the page variable declarations in the scriplets which I can't change.